# How do I get the word?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Get word from (in this thing the "test" changes after answering something)(It is in a #document):

```
<div class="au-target" au-target-id="137">Test</div>
```

Code:

```
word = driver.find_element_by_class_name('au-target')
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".au-target"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)
```

Comment: that HTML looks off why is there a = inside class?

Comment: Do you have anything in your code to give the browser time to render (a 'wait' or 'sleep')? If not it could be worth trying putting a short sleep before this assignment.

Comment: maybe you mis a dot like '.au-target', Please expand your HTML so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try highlighting that line of HTML, right click and copy and use the xpath. This is unique to that specific element in the website so it's better to use.

```py
word = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath pasted here')
```

If it doesn't work, it might be because the xpath is surrounded by single quotes so try double quotes

```py
word = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath pasted here")
```